# Aligning label values in dead code with gcc/clang

Tags: c, clang, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly, memory-alignment

On some compilers (I'm mostly interested in GCC/clang) with `void *jmp = &&label` you can get the address of a label you can later `goto jmp`. For an interpreter with pointer tagging, I want to align those labels to the next 8 byte boundary, so the label values all have 0b…000. Usually, you can align the instruction position with assembly, i.e. `__asm__ volatile(".p2align 8");` will pad the next instruction to the `2^8` byte with e.g. `NOP`s. However, because the interpreter won't have code between jump blocks, the assembly gets optimized out (or something – even with `volatile` it doesn't appear in the output.)

```
void test() {
    void *next = &&LABEL_A;
    goto *next;

/* won't get reached – optimized away? */
__asm__ volatile(".p2align 8");
LABEL_A:
    goto *next;
}
```

On [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s1nGebWP9) it shows the compiler doesn't align `LABEL_A`. However, when we change the code to

```
void test() {
    unsigned long foo = (unsigned long)&&LABEL;
    void *next = &&LABEL_A;
    goto *next;
LABEL:
__asm__ volatile(".p2align 8");
LABEL_A:
    goto *next;
}
```

The [output](https://godbolt.org/z/GKnxqj175) will show that `LABEL_A` got correctly padded – presumably because `LABEL` and the following statements couldn't get optimized away. However, this seems extremely fragile and doesn't work with `-O3`. Is there a better way?

I tried several `__attribute__(aligned(8), used)` attributes, `volatile` values/accesses between the blocks, though only the `LABEL` reference prevented the code elimination.

Comment: Yeah, it appears clang optimizes out the unreachable `asm` statement very early; even invalid instructions don't result in an error (like `asm("hi mom")` - https://godbolt.org/z/f3o6WdYvq - unlike GCC, clang would error if it was reachable even when generating a `.s` output since it uses its built-in assembler by default.).

Comment: Instead of introducing an extra label, what about putting your inline assembly immediately after `LABEL_A` instead of immediately before?  We're dealing with multiple areas of extensions and implemention-specific features, so I'm not sure about it, but that seems reasonably likely to work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger then the jump target doesn't get the padding, but the next instruction like `LABEL_A: nop nop … mov`. It seems I need to modify the assembly with some hacky regexes; luckily, at least `clang -S` annotates referenced labels with a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GCC, you should use the `-falign-labels=8` or the weaker `-falign-jumps=8` options.

You could put them in a function attribute: `__attribute__((optimise ("-falign-labels=8"))`.